# Embedded svg isn't scaled correctly

Tags: html, xml, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to embed an svg inside an svg (the real application is to be able to embed an image in a d3 chart). Here's a simplified version:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="80" style="fill:blue" />
  <image x="10" y="20" width="120" height="150" xlink:href="https://webkit.org/blog-files/circle.svg" />
</svg>
```

The embedded image scales correctly if it's a raster image (png/jpg), but not an svg. Here's a fiddle of it not working - the big red rectangle should actually be [this circle](https://webkit.org/blog-files/circle.svg).

https://jsfiddle.net/rg4kyuc7/1/

How do I get the svg to scale to the specified `width` and `height`?

Edit - working on Chrome but not Firefox?! Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of `<image>` changed a little between SVG 1.1 and the upcoming SVG 2.

It looks like Chrome is following the SVG 2 behaviour.  Chrome seems to be further along in implementing SVG 2 than other browsers.  The way it is displaying the embedded image would be wrong if it were still supporting only the SVG 1.1 standard.

Firefox (and IE, which is behaving the same) are both incorrect with respect to both SVG 1.1 *and* SVG 2.  The SVG 1.1 standard says that when the SVG file referenced by `<image>` has no `viewBox`, it should just be displayed at the position defined by the `x` and `y` attributes, and the `width` and the `height` of the `<image>` element is ignored.  In other words like this:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="80" style="fill:blue" />
  <image x="10" y="20" width="335" height="296" xlink:href="https://webkit.org/blog-files/circle.svg" />
</svg>
```

In any case, there is a simple fix.  Add an appropriate `viewBox` to `circle.svg` and it will render the same in all browsers, whether they support SVG 2 or not.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="335" height="296" viewBox="0 0 335 296">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've came across a similar issue where we ended up using the SVG's  tag.

This way you will be able to embed an html img tag in it and style it as such. Something like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="80" style="fill:blue" />
  <foreignObject x="10" y="20" width="120" height="150"
                   requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <img src="https://webkit.org/blog-files/circle.svg" alt="Smiley face" height="150" width="120">
      </body>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Here is the MDN documentation for

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject